# Ошибка в Вычислении ряда(функция)

Tags: c++, функции, ряды

```
#include <iostream> //
#include <math.h> //
using namespace std;
const int N = 3;

double sinus(double x) {
double res;
res = sin(x) / x;
return res;
}

double chislo(double z) {
int n;
double s = z, q = z;
double e;
for (n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
    q *= (-1)*z * z / (2 * n) / (2 * n + 1);
    s += q;

}
e = (pow(-1, n) * pow(z, 2*n)) / s;
return e;
}


int main()
{
int n;
double x;
double z;
cout << "Enter x= ";
cin >> x;
z = x;
x = sinus(x);
cout << x << endl;
cout << "--------"<<"\n";
z = chislo(z);
cout << z << endl;


}
```

Функция "chislo" неправильно вычисляет, а я не могу найти ошибку :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `int N = 3` и какую точность вы ожидаете при трёх итерациях? Не говоря уж о том, что это делается не так.

Comment: А как делается правильно?

Comment: @ewrika666 не нужно перевычислять одно и то же на каждой итерации. Каждый элемент ряда отличаеся о т предыдущего на определенный рациональный множитель, причем  квадрат х - его постоянный числитель. Это избавит от беды с факториалом. Не следует пользоваься pow () - это в свою очередь вычисление ряда.

Comment: Посмотрите ответы по метке "ряды"

Answer (score 1):

При нахождении рядов Тейлора следует избегать повторных вычислений и вычислять степени рекурсивно. Из-за того, что факториал растет очень быстро, при вычислениях с плавающей запятой теряются разряды и точность схождения.

Реализация вычисления N-й суммя ряда Тейлора для функции sinc может выглядеть вот так:

```
double taylor_sinc(double x, int N) {
    double x_2 = x*x , sinc = 1, elem = 1;
    
    for(int n = 1; n < N; ++n ){
      elem *= x_2;
      // (2n + 1)! = (2(n-1) + 1)! * (2n) * (2n + 1) 
      elem  /=  - (4*n*n + 2*n);
      sinc  +=  elem;  
    }
    return sinc;
}
```

Однако, в задании предлагается устанавливать границу ряда, что звучит как незнакомый термин, но явно это не граница сходимости  - она зависит только от самого ряда.